# I am trying to migrate an access97 sql query to SSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I am trying to migrate a query from access97 to ssms, I have been able to import the tables from access into ssms but I need to run (possible re-write) this query.
I know sql doesn't work with ! and & but I keep getting errors on these lines "([T2_BRA]![REF] & [F7])".
This is probably due to my lack of understanding in sql any advice would be great! 
Thanks

```
SELECT ([T2_BRA]![REF] & [F7]) AS NEWSTYLE,
       Suppliers.MasterSupplier,
       Dept.MasterDept,
       Colour.MasterColour,
       Colour.F7,
       T2_HEAD.SHORT,
       T2_HEAD.[DESC],
       T2_HEAD.[GROUP],
       T2_HEAD.STYPE,
       T2_HEAD.SIZERANGE,
       T2_HEAD.SUPPLIER,
       T2_HEAD.SUPPREF,
       T2_HEAD.VAT,
       T2_HEAD.BASESELL,
       T2_HEAD.SELL,
       T2_HEAD.SELLB,
       T2_HEAD.SELL1,
       SUM(T2_BRA.Q11) AS QTY1,
       SUM(T2_BRA.Q12) AS QTY2,
       SUM(T2_BRA.Q13) AS QTY3,
       SUM(T2_BRA.Q14) AS QTY4,
       SUM(T2_BRA.Q15) AS QTY5,
       SUM(T2_BRA.Q16) AS QTY6,
       SUM(T2_BRA.Q17) AS QTY7,
       SUM(T2_BRA.Q18) AS QTY8,
       SUM(T2_BRA.Q19) AS QTY9,
       SUM(T2_BRA.Q20) AS QTY10,
       SUM(T2_BRA.Q21) AS QTY11,
       SUM(T2_BRA.Q22) AS QTY12,
       SUM(T2_BRA.Q23) AS QTY13,
       T2_SIZES.S01,
       T2_SIZES.S02,
       T2_SIZES.S03,
       T2_SIZES.S04,
       T2_SIZES.S05,
       T2_SIZES.S06,
       T2_SIZES.S07,
       T2_SIZES.S08,
       T2_SIZES.S09,
       T2_SIZES.S10,
       T2_SIZES.S11,
       T2_SIZES.S12,
       T2_SIZES.S13,
       T2_HEAD.REF,
       Stocktype.MasterStocktype,
       SubDept.MasterSubDept,
       SUM(T2_BRA.LY11) AS LY1,
       SUM(T2_BRA.LY12) AS LY2,
       SUM(T2_BRA.LY13) AS LY3,
       SUM(T2_BRA.LY14) AS LY4,
       SUM(T2_BRA.LY15) AS LY5,
       SUM(T2_BRA.LY16) AS LY6,
       SUM(T2_BRA.LY17) AS LY7,
       SUM(T2_BRA.LY18) AS LY8,
       SUM(T2_BRA.LY19) AS LY9,
       SUM(T2_BRA.LY20) AS LY10,
       SUM(T2_BRA.LY21) AS LY11,
       SUM(T2_BRA.LY22) AS LY12,
       SUM(T2_BRA.LY23) AS LY13 
FROM Descriptions
     INNER JOIN T2_BRA ON Descriptions.T2TREF = T2_BRA.REF
     INNER JOIN T2_HEAD ON T2_BRA.REF = T2_HEAD.REF
     INNER JOIN Colour ON T2_BRA.COLOUR = Colour.NewCol
     INNER JOIN Suppliers ON T2_HEAD.SUPPLIER = Suppliers.SuppCode
     INNER JOIN Dept ON T2_HEAD.STYPE = Dept.DeptCode
     INNER JOIN T2_SIZES ON T2_HEAD.SIZERANGE = T2_SIZES.SIZERANGE
     INNER JOIN Stocktype ON T2_HEAD.[GROUP] = Stocktype.StkType
     LEFT JOIN SubDept ON T2_HEAD.USER2 = SubDept.SubDeptCode 
Group By ([T2_BRA]![REF] & [F7]),
         Suppliers.MasterSupplier,
         Dept.MasterDept,
         Colour.MasterColour,
         Colour.F7,
         T2_HEAD.Short,
         T2_HEAD.[Desc],
         T2_HEAD.[Group],
         T2_HEAD.STYPE,
         T2_HEAD.SIZERANGE,
         T2_HEAD.SUPPLIER,
         T2_HEAD.SUPPREF,
         T2_HEAD.VAT,
         T2_HEAD.BASESELL,
         T2_HEAD.SELL,
         T2_HEAD.SELLB,
         T2_HEAD.SELL1,
         T2_SIZES.S01,
         T2_SIZES.S02,
         T2_SIZES.S03,
         T2_SIZES.S04,
         T2_SIZES.S05,
         T2_SIZES.S06,
         T2_SIZES.S07,
         T2_SIZES.S08,
         T2_SIZES.S09,
         T2_SIZES.S10,
         T2_SIZES.S11,
         T2_SIZES.S12,
         T2_SIZES.S13,
         T2_HEAD.REF,
         Stocktype.MasterStocktype,
         SubDept.MasterSubDept 
ORDER BY ([T2_BRA]![REF] & [F7]) DESC;
```

Comment: Try changing ! to . and & to +

Comment: Technical note: you don't migrate to SSMS, SSMS is just a GUI (one of many) for SQL Server. The correct terminology is migrating to SQL Server, since that is the database engine. SSMS is just a tool by which you, as a user, happen to have decided to interact with the database engine. This is a touch pedantic but it's usually a good idea to be accurate and clear, use correct terminology, and to understand the role of the tools and components you're using.